# Page slows when loading react by ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webpage in php / html and is kind of onePage. Whenever I want to change the page I do it by ajax updating the content and changing the url by javascript without reloading the browser.

In one specific page I have one react application. If I navigate to this page multiple times, I can notice that the page bit a bit becomes slowly.

Is there a known problem with react about this or I can spend the time debugging my web?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with react. I'd be able to help you out if you provide a reproducible example or perhaps a link to the website. From what I can guess, maybe the react page has a lot of network calls which pile up every time you reopen the page. You can check your developer console to see if there are any memory leak errors from react.

Comment: It's complicated for me to provide an example. Could you tell me how can I check for memory leak in console? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I have to "unmount" react before mount it again to clean all events and state. In my case, the events were my problem.

I exposed the ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode function to windows and whenever I want to change the page I unmount the application.